# javascript/ jquery validation for time log(5h 3m)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have an input with the type of text. How to validate so that the user can enter only such values (5h 30m), it is for logging time(how much time was spent on a task). Should I use any regexp ?

Comment: Yes @Annie Alan , you are right. You can also check key codes to ensure the entered character is matching your requirements. Regex can be used to validate output when the input looses focus.

Comment: If you are still facing a problem, I will advise you, to put some code in your question. It will help others, to answer better. Good luck.

Comment: thanks, the regexp which starts only with numbers and can include 3 letters(h, m, s) and also space ?

Comment: Your requirement is pretty much valid. But also another point it should consider that the order of h m s is important. Can you create jsfiddle for this https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Will you always have hours and minutes or can you have only minutes for example ?

Comment: can have also minutes, can write for example 5h 30m (or even 30m 5h) or 30m or just 5h, can anybody help to write such a regexp?

Comment: Is your issue solved ?

Comment: yes, it is solved now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how to handle all cases at once but you can always test against several rexexp and see if you get a match.

- Hours and minutes : `/^\d{1,2}h\d{1,2}m$/i`
- Hours only : `/^\d{1,2}h$/i`
- Minutes only :  `/^\d{1,2}m$/i`
- Minutes and hours : `/^\d{1,2}m\d{1,2}h$/i`

```js
var pattern1 = /^\d{1,2}h\d{1,2}m$/i;
var pattern2 = /^\d{1,2}h$/i;
var pattern3 = /^\d{1,2}m$/i;
var pattern4 = /^\d{1,2}m\d{1,2}h$/i;

var reg1 = RegExp(pattern1);
var reg2 = RegExp(pattern2);
var reg3 = RegExp(pattern3);
var reg4 = RegExp(pattern4);

var test = function() {

  var toTest = document.getElementById('i').value;

  if (
    !reg1.test(toTest) &&
    !reg2.test(toTest) &&
    !reg3.test(toTest) &&
    !reg4.test(toTest)
  ) alert('Not OK');
  else alert('OK');
}
```

```html
<input id="i" type="text" value="" />
<input type="button" value="Test" onclick="test();" />
```

Comment: Try now I missed the string termination symbol. For example 1h30m, 1h, 30m should return OK.

Comment: do you know any good tutorial in order to learn regular expressions?